# Different app resolution between iPhone 8 and iPhone 6,7 with same settings

Tags: ios, camera, resolution, preview, iphone-8

we are developing an app that get images (640x480) from the rear camera and process it. Preview and images are displaced to top and right of the screen on the iPhone 8, but on iPhone 7 works perfectly as we want. We think the problem could be the values of focal length (fh,fv) set. As we know iPhone 7 & 8 has the same model of cameras and screen, but the response is different with the same settings. Any of you had the same problem or know how solve it?.

iPhone 8 incorrect behaviour (displaced at right and top).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RcGA.jpg

Correct beahaviour, centered in the middle of the screen (iPhone 7).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2iMH.jpg

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: upload screenshot or diagram for better understanding

Comment: add some images or video which makes your problem to understand it better

Comment: Maybe the problem is image scaling? Try to work with imageView.contentMode

Comment: Edited post with links of screenshoots. Thanks!.